# Adding a new line of text to text file

Tags: powershell

I have this function to look inside a document. Basically, I'm looking for some missing data and add it. 
So for example a complete data would look like:

```
SubTotal :           30,473.00
%IVA     :            3,960.00
%SER     :            3,047.00
TOTALES  :           37,483.00
```

But if any of those lines are missing, I have to add it with a Zero value. So far this is the function that looks for it. Seems to work, but I don't know what to do its how to add the missing data to that specific line using PowerShell

Here is the function:

```
    function leeyedita() 
    {
        $content = Get-Content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++) {
           $line = $content[$i]
           $nextLine = $content[$i+1]

           if ($line.StartsWith("SubTotal")-and ($nextline.StartsWith("%SER"))) {
               Write-Host "NO ENCONTRE IVA"
               Write-Host $content[$i]
               # Replace the line with the Replacement Line Text.
           } 

           elseif ($line.StartsWith("%IVA")-and ($nextline.StartsWith("TOTALES"))) {
                Write-Host "NO ENCONTRE SERVICIO"
           }    

           else {
              #Write-Host "NO ES"
           }
       }
    }

Thanks a lot for the help!

UPDATE: 

Sometimes the file can have 2 totals :

    TOTALES  :         14,383.00
    Descuento Aplicado:          1,598.00
    TOTALES :     14,383.00


I want to delete the second one, so I created an if condition 

    elseif ($line.StartsWith("Descuento Aplicado")-and ($nextline.StartsWith("TOTALES"))) {
            Replace the line with the Replacement Line Text.
            Write-Host "ENCONTRE DESCUENTO" -fore white 
            $newcontent += ""

       }

That would create a blank line. But I want to delete the line. Is there a way?
Thanks!
```

UPDATE 8 OCTOBER 2018:

I'm facing a new problem. The problem is that when the file comes without service (%SER) and you apply a discount the script will write the correct 0 ammount but will not delete the first totales.

I need to delete the first totales everytime I get it (which only happens when a discount (Descuento Aplicado) has a value in the file. I dont know why its not executing the else if function that mets that condition....

```
elseif ($line.StartsWith("TOTALES")-and (!$previousLine.StartsWith("DescuentoAplicado")-and ($booldesc-eq 1))) 



SubTotal:           8,122.00
%IVA    :             959.00
%SER    :             0.00
TOTALES :           9,073.00
DescuentoAplicado:             918.00
TOTALES :      9,073.00
(COLONES)
```

This is the updated code:

```
   function leeyedita() 
{
    write-host "FUNCION LEE Y EDITA TXT" -fore white 
    $content = Get-Content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt
    $newcontent = @()
    $boolserv=0
    $booliva=0
    $boolpropina=0
    $booldesc=0



    for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++){

       $line = $content[$i]

     if ($line.StartsWith("DescuentoAplicado"))

       {
       $booldesc=1
       }

     elseif ($line.StartsWith("%IVA"))

       {
       $booliva=1
       }

     elseif ($line.StartsWith("%SER"))

       {
       $boolserv=1
       }

     elseif ($line.StartsWith("PROPINA"))

       {
       $boolpropina=1
       }


}
Write-Host "SERV $boolserv IVA $booliva PROP $boolpropina DESC $booldesc"

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++){

       $line = $content[$i]
       $previousLine = $content[$i-1]
       $nextLine = $content[$i+1]


       if ($line.StartsWith("SubTotal")-and ($booliva-eq 0)) {
           # Replace the line with the Replacement Line Text.
            Write-Host "NO ENCONTRE IVA" -fore white            
            $newcontent += $line 
            $newcontent += '{0, 0}'-f"%IVA : 0.00"
            $booliva=1

       }


       elseif ($line.StartsWith("TOTALES")-and ($boolserv-eq 0)) {
           # Replace the line with the Replacement Line Text.
            Write-Host "NO ENCONTRE SERVICIO" -fore white 
            $newcontent += '{0, 0}'-f"%SER : 0.00"
            $newcontent += $line
            $boolserv=1 


       }

       elseif ($line.StartsWith("TOTALES")-and($booldesc-eq 0)) {
           # Replace the line with the Replacement Line Text.
            Write-Host "NO ENCONTRE DESCUENTO" -fore white 
            $newcontent += '{0, 0}'-f"DescuentoAplicado : 0.00"
            $newcontent += $line
            $booldesc=1 
       }

       elseif ($line.StartsWith("TOTALES")-and (!$previousLine.StartsWith("DescuentoAplicado")-and ($booldesc-eq 1))) {
           # Replace the line with the Replacement Line Text.
            Write-Host "ENCONTRE DESCUENTO" -fore white


       }


       else {
            #Write-Host "LINEA NORMAL"
            $newcontent += $line
            }



            #Write-Host "ESCRIBIENDO ARCHIVO"
            $newcontent | out-file $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt   

       } 


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to initialize an empty array (`$newcontent`) before you iterate over the content of `$content`, populate `$newcontent` with the desired content and then output it to a text file:

```
function leeyedita() 
{
    $content = Get-Content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt

    # Initialize empty array
    $newcontent = @()

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++) {
       $line = $content[$i]
       $nextLine = $content[$i+1]

       if ($line.StartsWith("SubTotal")-and ($nextline.StartsWith("%SER"))) {
           Write-Host "NO ENCONTRE IVA"
           Write-Host $content[$i]

           # Add the current line and then the missing IVA line 
           $newcontent += $line
           $newcontent += "%IVA : 0.00"
       } 

       elseif ($line.StartsWith("%IVA")-and ($nextline.StartsWith("TOTALES"))) {
            Write-Host "NO ENCONTRE SERVICIO"

            # Add the current line and then the missing SER line 
            $newcontent += $line 
            $newcontent += "%SER : 0.00"
       }    

       else {
          #Write-Host "NO ES"

          # Add current line
          $newcontent += $line
       }
   }

   # Output new content to file
   $newcontent | out-file $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt   
}
```

If the you care about aligning the new text in the same way as the other text entries, take a look on [how to format strings in powershell](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)

Comment: Instead of inefficiently rebuilding the array each time with `$newcontent +=` assign the whole `For` and internal output to the variable `$newcontent = for (...`

Comment: Is there a way to extend the new string? So I have everything in the same column? Like the original text but with 0

SubTotal :           30,473.00
%IVA     :            0.00
%SER     :          0.00
TOTALES  :        30,483.00

Comment: @JuanManuelSanchez to answer your second question: simply remove `$newcontent += ""` and you will not have the blank line

Comment: that did it ! Thanks !

Comment: @JoeBigToe how would it be if I want to delete the previous line? So Instead of having 

TOTALES  :         14,383.00
Descuento Aplicado:          1,598.00
TOTALES :     14,383.00

Just have 
Descuento Aplicado:          1,598.00
TOTALES :     14,383.00

Comment: I updated the question... this is getting more tricky that I though or my programming skill are really low since I did it for the last time 10 years ago...

Comment: shortly, if you want to eliminate the last line from `$newcontent` you should write a line of code like this `$newcontent = $newcontent[0..($newcontent.length-2)]`